# Oracle Live SQL: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to show first_name, last_name columns and make UPPER-CASE LETTERS for those entries who have the letter 's' in the last name.

I am getting

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

error. Anyone has an idea where I go wrong and How do I fix it?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE last_name LIKE "S"
UPDATE CUSTOMERS 
SET 
    first_name = UPPER(first_name)
    last_name = UPPER(last_name)
```

Comment: You can do either SELECT or UPDATE. Not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS 
SET first_name = UPPER(first_name), last_name = UPPER(last_name)
WHERE last_name LIKE '%S%'
```

It is unclear whether you want to match on upper-case or lower-case "s" in the name. If you want both, then:

```
WHERE UPPER(last_name) LIKE '%S%'
```

Comment: It fixed making the last names uppercase but can I also show/view the columns first name and last name in the same code?

Comment: @Adam: you can't `SELECT` and `UPDATE` at the same time in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

try putting "%S" instead of "S". If you put "S" it will only show you results for surnames that are just the letter S

Comment: Possibly you mean "%S%"

Comment: Yeah, you're right if you put "%S" it shows you the names that end with S. If you put "%S%" it will display the names that have the letter S inside

Answer (score 0):

Try following with subquery:-

```
UPDATE  CUSTOMERS 
SET  ( first_name ,    last_name ) = (SELECT  UPPER(first_name) ,  UPPER(last_name)  FROM CUSTOMERS   )
WHERE UPPER(last_name)  LIKE 'S'
```

However, if you want all last_name starting with S then add wildcard such as

```
WHERE UPPER(last_name) LIKE 'S%'
```